# Rmarkdown: How to use code chunk from other Rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown

How to use code chunk from child document in another Rmd file? I have one parent document named `figures.Rmd` which have following structure

```
`{r child='force.Rmd',echo=F,ref.label='pressure'}
`


some text 
`{r child='force.Rmd',echo=F,ref.label='cars'}
```

and the child document named `force.Rmd` which have following structure

```
`{r, cars,echo=F}
options(knitr.duplicate.label = 'allow')

plot(cars)
`



`{r, pressure,echo=F}
options(knitr.duplicate.label = 'allow')

summary(pressure)
`
```

I want to read some chunks from the `force.Rmd` in the `figures.Rmd`. I am getting some output but it is producing the output 2 times. So basically I have 2 or 3 chunks in `force.Rmd` which I want to use at different places in `figures.Rmd` . How can I do that without getting the output 2 times?

Comment: Please tell us more about your file structure. Can you provide minimal working examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `parent.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "parent"
author: "Me"
date: "2023-01-25"
output: html_document
---

## Parent

This is parent 

## Some part of child 

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
invisible(knitr::purl("child.Rmd", output="temp", quiet=TRUE))
read_chunk("temp")
```

```{r ref.label='cars'}
```

## Some text

Here I am.

## Some other part of child

## Some part of child 

```{r ref.label='pressure'}
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
unlink("temp")
```
````

This is `child.Rmd`

````
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````

I can call each single child chunk at various positions:

[image]

Comment: yes but what if I have more than 1 chunk to read from child document? for example you want to read the pressure chunk as well, what will the code in that case?

Comment: ok thankyou it's working. Can you please explain what's the role of 'temp' ? and unlinking it eventually?

Comment: You can read something about *purling* here https://exeter-data-analytics.github.io/LitProg/r-markdown.html#purling When `purl()` produces an external script, code chunks can be read via `read_chunk()` . `unlink()` deletes the temporary script, you can try it without `unlink()` it will produce a file named *temp*